# Enforce python 2.7 to run my script - cannot import name 'urlencode'

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terminal, pip

I try to run a script. Like so:

```
$ ./script_I_downloaded.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

and I am getting the following error:

> cannot import name 'urlencode'

This error seems to be related to python3. The script I'm running is using python2. I would thus like to execute it using python2. I do have pyhton 2.7 on my system. However, when I try to do ...

```
$ python2 ./script_I_downloaded.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

...I get an error, because now argument no. 1 is argument no.2, so the script fails. How can I force this script to execute under python2?

PS: I found some solutions online saying I should change something in the imports, but I do not want to mess with the scripts source, since I don't understand much of it and it's not my own script. I am on OS X.

Comment: Presumably the script has a shebang line as the first line of the file. Can you edit it to point at a different `python`?

Comment: I just had a look. It says `#!/usr/bin/env python2` -which looks correct to me. I'm trying a few more things out with this one. Thank you.

Comment: What does `python2 -V` show? Are you sure the import error is coming from that script (and not from some other script it tries to launch, for example)? I think you'll need to provide enough code for someone else to reproduce the issue, otherwise the only thing anyone can do is guess.

Comment: `python2 -V` gives me: `Python 2.7.14`. and ` which python2` gives me: `/usr/local/bin/python2` which is different from the shebang line in the script (which is `#!/usr/bin/env python2`) might this be an issue?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` will look up the first `python2` on your PATH. So unless you are doing something weird with your environment, that will be the same version as what you get when you type a bare `python2`. I suspect very strongly that the script *is* running with Python 2, and the error you're getting has nothing to do with Python 3.